# sql server jobs stays in executing mode at specific time

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I have called the .bat file in procedure and scheduled it through a job for every 5 minutes.

It is executing fine throughout the day (every 5 minutes) but remains in execution mode at 1.30 AM.

At that time, if I disabled the job and enabled again it's running fine.

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: You need to see why the commands inside your batch take longer at that time. Maybe you have scheduled some backups at that time? Without knowing what your batch does and what other operations you have at that time, it will be hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks, we have scheduled the reports at that time.